# Matching value from list to column value in data-frame and extracting the adjacent value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a list,

```
like_zips = [0, 1001, 1002, 1005, 1007, 1010, 1013, 1020, 1027, 1028, 1030,...]
```

and a dataframe of two columns:

```
   zip     AGI
    0   11004990.0
1   0   17658446.0
2   0   15963943.0
3   0   14294375.0
4   0   27387096.0
5   0   22652783.0
```

I'm trying to match elements in the list with their occurrences in the DF, so where the zips (list element and column element) match I would like to average all the AGI values of matching the list element and then append that specific list element as a key with its now averaged values as the value into a dictionary

So ideally something like this:

```
matched_zip_means = {}

for i in like_zips:
    if IRS_AGI_only['zipcode'].isin(like_zips) == True:
        a = IRS_AGI_only.loc[IRS_AGI_only['zip'] == i, 'AGI'].mean()
        matched_zip_means[i] = a

print(matched_zip_means)
```

I know I can use a groupby, but the list and data frames are extremely large, and I was wondering if there was a computationally "non-suicidal" alternative for doing this?

EDIT:

As requested the ideal output would look like:

```
zip_dict = [0 : "mean AGI value of 0", 1001 : "mean AGI of 1001" ... etc]
```

EDIT 2:

```
matched_zip_means = {}

for i in like_zips:
    if i in IRS_AGI_only['zipcode']:
        a = round(IRS_AGI_only.loc[IRS_AGI_only['zipcode'] == i, 'A00100'].mean(), 2)
        matched_zip_means[i] = a
```

This works, but I'm wondering if there is anything that's faster maybe? This took about 30s

Comment: Can you provide the desired output for your sample data?

Comment: Sure! `zip_dict = ['0' : "mean AGI of 0", '32259' : 'mean AGI of 32259']`